# Why in google chrome pop up window is shown in different location then in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I hjave a javascript function that opens a new window:

my index.htm page has 3 links:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href = "javascript:openContent('jobsearch.htm', 875, 1300, 0, 300)">Job Search</a><br />
        <a href = "javascript:openContent('details.htm?page_id=7&details_id=7',875, 1300, 0, 300)">Job Details</a><br />
        <a href = "javascript:openContent('apply.htm?page_id=10&details_id=7', 875, 1300, 0, 300)">Apply</a><br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

My `openContent` function:

```
function openContent(url, width, height, top, left) 
{
   var win;
   win = window.open(url, 'content', "toolbar=no, titlebar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=" + top + ", left=" + left + ", width=" + width + ", height=" + height + "\"");
   win.focus();
}
```

When clicking the links in index.htm page I open certain page and on `firefox` and `IE`, window opens at the same location, but on `chrome` it opens at the left most location on thr page.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid using native pop up windows as much as possible for the following reasons:

1. A lot of browsers block them by default.
2. Each browser presents them differently.
3. They are generally conceived as annoying.

A good alternativ is [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated), which gives you more control over how it's presented.

However if you insist on using native pop ups you can try the `moveTo` function, example:

```
function example() {
    var win = window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/", 'content', "toolbar=no, titlebar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, width=500, height=500");
    win.focus();
    win.moveTo(50, 50);
}
```

It worked for me in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and IE.